# Convert arf to mp4 or play arf

Tags: 16.04, video, webex

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. It is very frustrating from Cisco side that they still do not provide anything for 64-bit linux.
As webex is not working, I am missing online sessions. To further surprise, nbr2mp4 is not able to convert arf to mp4. It is stuck for hours with no sign of progress.

Is there any other alternative way (online or offline) to convert arf to mp4. Even if nbr2mp4 has some issue, let me know how to solve.

Comment: Are you able to post one of the problem files online?

Comment: Please mention where to post?

Comment: I have found DataFile Host the easiest: http://www.datafilehost.com/

Comment: Content is for registered user. It cannot be posted online.

Comment: FWIW, there's a native Linux version of WebEx that you can use.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Can you provide the link?

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to [sign up](https://www.webex.de/products/web-conferencing.html) for their service (there's a free service tier) and then you can download the client software.